# Using Classes to Style in CSS

Tags: css, cellspacing

I've got a table, and inside of the table are  elements. I would like to give the table one class "chart" and then style all of the  elements that are inside of that table by giving them padding.

Is this possible?

I was thinking something like...

```
info.table.td{
    padding:2px;
}
```

Would be possible, but it does not work :V I know that . is sort of the class operator, but I thought it would make sense on a tag type as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`info.table.td` means an `<info>` element with the classes `table` and `td` (which is nonsense).

You probably mean `table.info td`, which means any `td` that is a child of a `table` with the class `info`.

Comment: @alex Oh no, I just meant that there's no such thing as an `<info>` element. :P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `info` is the ID to a container element, try this:

```
#info table td { padding: 2px; }
```

Comment: Woops! This is close. But # are for IDs, I want to style all the tables the same way, hence they have a class, not an ID

Comment: No worries. I misunderstood you. Looks like deceze has you taken care of.